# C# - Sending Email From Within SHarepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I would like to send an email from within sharepoint to a user on the local domain, after an event reciever has been triggered.

How would I go about this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many Thanks,

Freddie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't really gave much context to your question, so I'm just going to point out the simplest alternative.

In most situations, you should be just be able to use one of the [`SPUtility.SendMail(..)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.sendemail?view=sharepoint-server#Microsoft_SharePoint_Utilities_SPUtility_SendEmail_Microsoft_SharePoint_SPWeb_System_Boolean_System_Boolean_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_) overloads

So, something like this should be sufficient
var headers = new StringDictionary();
    headers.Add("from", from);

```
headers.Add("to", to);
headers.Add("cc", cc);
headers.Add("bcc", bcc);

headers.Add("subject", subject);

headers.Add("content-type", "text/html");
SPUtility.SendEmail(web, headers, body);
```

That said, keep in mind that SPUtility.SendEmail isn't very robust (sometimes, it won't even point out if an error occurred while sending the mail...).

For this reason, some sources prefer to just use the well documented [`SmtpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.send?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_Mail_SmtpClient_Send_System_Net_Mail_MailMessage_) instead. In that case, the only problematic part is getting the outbound email server address.

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = currentWeb.Site.WebApplication.OutboundMailServiceInstance.Server.Address;
```

As you can see, one possible option is getting it from the web application associated to the current web site (that is, assuming you have a valid SPContext at the time and are therefore able to access the current web site in the first place). From here, just build the `MailMessage` instance and send it using `client.Send(message);`.